# how to create nested JSON object in php?

Tags: php, json

What is the correct way to define this kind of JSON object in PHP

```
  [
    {
        "id": 1111,
        "tahun": 2019,
        "nilai": 9123,
        "detail": [
            {
              "id": 0,
              "nilai": 0
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
```

I need to create a nested array that will be converted to JSON object via json_encode()

```
class Service {
    public $id = 1111;
    public $tahun = 2019;
    public $nilai = 9123;
    public $detail = array();

    function  __construct(){
        for ( $i=3; $i-->0;){
            array_push($this->detail, new Detail);
        }
    }
}

class Detail {
    public $id = 1;
    public $nilai = 2000;
}
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode([new Service],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
```

How to create output like that without using class?

Comment: Did you try something before posting the question here? Share your code here

Comment: if you know what the JSON *should* look like, you can always `json_decode()` it to see what it produces in PHP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no code effort shown.

Comment: how to create that without using this class..like this code...'class Service {
    public $id = 1111;
    public $tahun = 2019;
    public $nilai = 9123;
    public $detail = array();

    function  __construct(){
        for ( $i=3; $i-->0;){
            array_push($this->detail, new Detail);
        }
    }
}

class Detail {
    public $id = 1;
    public $nilai = 2000;
}
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode([new Service],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';'

Comment: i'm sorry guys..i'm newbie in stackoverflow....

Comment: This is stuff people IMHO should be learning from a beginner’s tutorial that explains the basics of working with PHP’s data types, instead of dragging it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create multi array and as per u know you have to use `json_encode`

```
$array = array("id" => "1111",  
              "tahun" => "tahun",
              "detail" => array( array( "id" => "0", "nilai" => "0" ) )
              );

echo json_encode( $data = array( $array ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array with an array inside.

```
json_encode(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c'=>array('a1'=>1, 'b2'=>2), 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
```

with json_encode() you will get

```
{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 
            {
              "a1": 1,
              "b1": 1
            }

        "d"=>4,
        "e"=>5
}
```

with echo it out put this

> {"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"a1":1,"b2":2},"d":4,"e":5}

Answer (score 0):

by a simple nested array

```
   $json_array = array(
            "id"=> 1111,
            "tahun" => 2019,
            "nilai"=> 9123,
            "detail" => array(array(
                "id" => 0,
                  "nilai" => 0
            ) )
        );

    echo json_encode($json_array);
```